# Insert a Valid GPB from WKT

Tags: geopackage, odbc

My software produce WKT and I'm trying to import it into an ODBC connected Geopackage:

```
SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');

SELECT IsValidGPB(
    AsGPB (
        ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((  318830.663 301484.952 18.120,
                                    318821.415 301490.594 18.405,
                                    318814.969 301480.037 18.489,
                                    318824.223 301474.375 18.132,
                                    318830.663 301484.952 18.120))'
                        , 3163
        )
    )
) AS "IsValid?";

Result: 0
```

Is there a trick to make a valid GPB geom?

Comment: Wow, it works in 2D...

Comment: If SpatiaLite does not consider the geopackage geometry that it just created as valid there must be a bug. Make sure that you use the most recent version and if issue still happens write mail to SpatiaLite users forum.

Answer (score 1):

So in 2D, the result is 1...

```
SELECT IsValidGPB(
    AsGPB (
        ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((318830.663 301484.952,318821.415 301490.594,318814.969 301480.037 ,318824.223 301474.375,318830.663 301484.952 ))', 3163)
    )
) AS "IsValid?";
```